# Как узнать остаток денег на счету в личном кабинете Google-AdWords?

Tags: google-adwords

Как узнать остаток денег на счету и пополнить счет в личном кабинете в Google-AdWords?

Т.е. неизрасходованных еще средств, которые остались на счету клиента в сервисе Google-AdWords?

Comment: программно или вручную? если второе, то вопрос оффтопик, если первое то не указан язык программирования. Итого - вопрос закрыть.

Comment: Это очень важный вопрос для тех, кто пользуется AdWords. 
Гугл манехо усложил этот момент - мы ему подсказываем! Догадаться тут реально не просто. Такой важный показатель должен быть наглядным, а его спрятали глубоко. Нужно знать цепочку входа...

Comment: Я звонил в поддержку Google Мне дали этот ответ я хочу им поделиться Чем этот вопрос не угодил? Почему закрыть? Хоть кто-нибудь ответьте

Comment: Объясните за что вы минусуете?

Comment: Объявлен 2 дня назад требующим правки участниками A K, 0xdb, Viktor Tomilov, Eugene Krivenja, iluxa1810, так как непонятна суть вопроса! - Объясните, пожалуйста, что значит: не понятна суть вопроса? Он же простой и понятный

Comment: Каким образом вопрос "как посмотреть баланс" относится к программированию? НИКАК. Поэтому вопрос ОФФТОПИК для нашего сайта. Сайт посвящён программированию, а не тому, как узнать баланс клиента. Если бы баланс нужно было узнать программно, как курс валют запросить через API центробанка - тогда да, был бы онтопик. Нетематические вопросы должны выпиливаться и минусоваться. Почему вам вообще пришло в голову задавать подобный вопрос на stackoverflow? Есть же более подходящие сайты, например, когда я работал с Adwords и Директом я писал на форуме searchengines.ru.

Comment: Спасибо @A K. Понятно.  Но здесь есть тег Adwords и я видел много организационно касающихся программирования вопросов на англоязычном SO - весьма позитивно и активно обсуждаемых НО ВОПРОС ТО ЗАКРЫВАЮТ НЕ ПО УКАЗАННОЙ ВАМИ ПРИЧИНЕ! ПОЧЕМУ НАПИСАНА ДРУГАЯ ПРИЧИНА? БЫЛО СЛОЖНО ВЫРАЗИТЬ НА РУССКОМ ЯЗЫКЕ?

Comment: @A K Мне же не рекомендовано его удалить А править рекомендавно! Я правлю - меня минусуют! ) Это честно?

Comment: Объявлен 2 дня назад требующим правки участниками A K, 0xdb, Viktor Tomilov, Eugene Krivenja, iluxa1810, так как непонятна суть вопроса.
Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему. - Я очень стараюсь выполнить все эти рекомендации а меня минусуют...

Comment: И я же не пишу в тегах языков программирования Я пишу в существующем на сайте теге Google-Adwords

Comment: Ещё более подробно [объяснил причину закрытия в чате сообщества](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43041909#43041909).

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что никак не относится к программированию и оффтопик

Comment: @user к сожалению, на SO есть достаточно четкий онтопик - программирование и системное администрирование. AdWords - это инструмент маркетологов, никакого отношения к программированию он не имеет. Да, на сайте есть тэг [tag:google-adwords] - он он предназначен для вопросов по использованию соответсвующего API. Т.е. если бы вы хотели узнать баланс при помощи кода - ваш ответ был бы онтопиком. Но ваш вопрос сводится к каким-то особенностям интерфейса для конечного пользователя - так что извините, но это не попадает под список разрешенных на сайте тем.

Comment: @user если вы считаете, что использование инструментов для маркетологов должно быть включено в онтопик - создайте соответствующее обсуждение на https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что он не относится к программированию или администрированию, а наличие ответа не делает его [вопросом по тематике ресурса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: от того, что Вы добавили метки без описания он не стал онтопиком

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Зайти **Личный кабинет** на сайте www.adwords.google.com
2. Войти в "**Гаечный Ключ**" (см. Рис.1)
3. В выпадающем меню, в самой правой колонке **НАСТРОЙКА** выбрать **Счета и платежи** (см. Рис.2)
4. Будет выведен **Остаток** !

P.S. Кстати, там же можно и пополнить счет

Рис.1

[image: Рис.1]

Рис.2

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]